# gnuplot map view customizing color

Tags: gnuplot

As seen, the default colour in map-view in Gnuplot for zero value  is black. I want to make it white and display other colours for other data. May you tell me how to customise the colours please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the help for `palette`:

```
gnuplot> help set palette
```

After setting the palette, you give for example `with points palette` to the `splot` command.

Comment: I have done this: [set view map;splot '1.dat'u 1:2:0.0:3 with points palette] It takes black colour for the zero values and rest for the other data. I want the zero value to be white. May you tell me what is lacking to this please?

Comment: @ndphysics: You need to `set palette ...`.  If you start gnuplot by entering just `gnuplot` on a shell, you get the gnuplot prompt (`gnuplot>` above).  There, you enter `help set palette` to find out how to use that.  Alternatively, download http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.4/gnuplot.pdf and look at chapter 75.53 on page 131.